# Partial loading of entity from existing table

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

**UPDATE:**

Sorry guys, I had an error after downgrading to `EFCore` from `5.0` to `3.1.` I thought this error was due to me trying to create a context with `DBSet<Entity_StuffINeed>`. In reality, a clean and rebuild solved the issue. The bug for context.

> System.TypeLoadException: 'Method 'Create' in type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Query.Internal.SqlServerSqlTranslatingExpressionVisitorFactory' from assembly 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer, Version=3.1.13.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60' does not have an implementation.'

**ORIGINAL:**

I'm connecting to an existing database and can't edit the tables. The entity is very large. I used scaffolding to get the model classes.

```
public partial class Entity_Database
{
    public Entity_Database()
    {
        CollectionRef1 = new HashSet<CollectionRef1 >();
        ... (12 other collectiosn here)
        CollectionRef13 = new HashSet<CollectionRef13 >();
    }

    public int Prop1 { get; set; }
    ...(47 other props here)
    public int? Prop48 { get; set; }

    public virtual Ref1 Ref1 { get; set; }
    ...
    public virtual Ref12 Ref12 { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<CollectionRef1> CollectionRef1 { get; set; }
    ...
    public virtual ICollection<CollectionRef13> CollectionRef13 { get; set; }
}
```

But I only need a small portion of these properties.

```
public class Entity_StuffINeed
{
    public int Prop1 {get;set;}
    public string Prop4 {get;set;}
    public DateTime Prop8 {get;set;}
}
```

I could use SQL and then map to my object manually:

```
SELECT Prop1, Prop4, Prop8 FROM Entity_Database;
```

But I can't find a way to do something similar in EFcore.

- If I try to use the scaffolding context, startup takes multiple minutes.
- If i try to use Entity_StuffINeed as a DBSet I get an error when I try to access the DBSet "Create from EFCore SqlServer does not have an implementation". (This makes sense since if I edit an element it would not know how to propagate those changes back to the database)

My guess is I'm using the wrong tool. Dapper doesn't allow for Linq syntax which I vastly prefer. If it's impossible in EFcore, what should I use?

Comment: Google for "EF projection". Edit, note this will disable entity tracking

Comment: You use `dbContext.LargeTable.Select(new { Prop1, Prop4, Prop8 })`?

Comment: @CodeCaster I have tried this code. The issue is there are so many complicated navigation properties in Entity_Database that startup is taking very long (I stopped after 3 minutes of loading, this is supposed to be in Azure Functions). If I remove any of these navigation properties I get the error: System.TypeLoadException: 'Method 'Create' in type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Query.Internal.SqlServerSqlTranslatingExpressionVisitorFactory' from assembly 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer' does not have an implementation.'

Comment: Create your own context in which you map only the part of the entity that needs editing. Or remove everything you don't need in the scaffolded entity.

Comment: Have you considered views? if you create views in your own schema (even DBAs of 3rd party DBs are often open to this) then scaffold or manually map EF to the views. If its only a single table, projection would be enough. If this multiple tables?

Comment: I'm really sorry everyone. Turns out it is possible to create a context that is different from the initial table (as Gert Arnold suggested). The error was due to me moving back to EFCore 3.1 from EFCore 5.0 (required for Azure Functions). A clean and rebuild solved the bug.

@ChrisSchaller thanks for the suggestion. Briefly googling this looks like a great suggestion I'll look into it